# Does "Interesting take" mean "Interesting scene"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

Does "Interesting take" mean "Interesting scene"?

jason@calacanis.com tweeted:

> Crypto and #stimmy checks are giving us a great preview of what a world with UBI will be like
> Swaths of people passing on going to work, restaurants unable to find servers, robotic companies being asked to “go faster!”

Sam Harris replies:

> Interesting take. Get @AndrewYang on your podcast to discuss.

Source: [Twitter](https://twitter.com/Jason/status/1391108021611282434)

Answer (score 12):

> [**take**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/take#Noun), noun
> 3. An interpretation or view, opinion or assessment; perspective.
> *What's your **take** on this issue, Fred?*

Comment: Thanks. So UBI stands for Universal Basic Income there?

Comment: @NewPlanet, yes.